# Device File Explorer сброс настроек

Tags: android-studio

Можно ли как-то сбросить приложения для открывания файла в Device File Explorer по умолчанию не сбрасывая вообще все настройки?

Android Studio 3.1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

Перейдите в

`Setting -> Editor -> File Types`

Выберите в верхнем окне `Recognized File Types` формат файла, который вы хотите связать/отвязать от паттерна типа файла и в нижнем окне либо добавьте новый паттерн вида `*.<паттерн файла>` (например `*.txt` ) нажав `+`, либо удалите нажав `-`. Можно также отредактировать имеющийся.

[Ссылка](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.3/creating-and-registering-file-types.html#create)

Comment: Отличный ответ, спасибо